# Java Date Calculation Inside XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I've been struggling to figure out how to accomplish a seemingly easy date calculation with Java and XSLT, so I have put down my stubborn hat and humbled my self to asking. I don't have a lot of experience with Java and XSL, I'm figuring it out as I go

What I've managed to get right so far is to get the current date (formatted in DDMMM), like so...

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:text.SimpleDateFormat.new('ddMMM'),
 java:util.Date.new())"/>
```

Now, what I really need to do is get the previous days date ie. Today - 1

This uses `xml version=1.0` and I have no control of the namespace or stylesheet. This needs to be purely done with the Java engine.

I've searched and found a few resources on this, but none of them work because they assume that I have the capability to change the namespace etc.

For context, I'm trying to accomplish this in SAS Digital Marketing Studio

Comment: You need to tell us which XSLT processor you are using. I suspect Xalan, but that's only a guess. If you're using Saxon, then of course you get all the XSLT 2.0 date/time handling for free and you don't need to call out to Java. Simple date arithmetic then becomes a trivial problem.

Comment: @MichaelKay OP specify that this needs to be purely done with the Java engine (perhaps an however or w/e).

Comment: @MichaelKay The software uses Xalan, and yes I wish it was XSLT2.0. Would have been so much easier.

Comment: "*This needs to be purely done with the Java engine.*" Why? Not that there's anything wrong with using Java (given that Xalan supports it), but you could also do this in XSLT, with a little help from EXSLT (the part that Xalan supports).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass yesterday's timestamp as long parameter to Date constructor.

```
<xsl:variable name="currentTimeStamp" select="current-dateTime()-24*60*60*1000"/>
<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:text.SimpleDateFormat.new('ddMMM'),
                      java:util.Date.new({$currentTimeStamp})"/>
```

Comment: Thank Jean-François, that seemed like a very promising solution. But unfortunately when I pass the parameter to the constructor, I get no output at all. Would have been great if the software gave some sort of error, but I can only see when it fails to compile. Which, in this case, it doesn't. Is there any other way to do this?